# What tools do I need for program in visual studio with Data Bases?

Tags: mysql, database, forms, visual-studio

I'm looking to make a simple program in Visual Studio with forms and all that, so I want to know what I need to manage my databases, import them so that I can use them to display information on forms.

Ty from your answers, I'm really confused right now, that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: so you want to connect vs code to an mysql server is that the question or should some code do that ?

Comment: Actually that's my question, I want to use Visual Studio 2019 and connect it to a database manager (MySQL), but I don't know how to do it, what do I need to install? or what barriers may appear? I searched for information on the internet, but the amount of different tutorials and web pages overwhelms me and now I am lost.

Comment: I would consider a tool like DBeaver to connect to a mysql server but you have to specify your question more.